# Data.Bytestring length gives wrong length

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a program that uses the length of an input string as part of the calculation.

I want to use ByteString to speed things up as the input string can be extremely long (Note: I dont really know what ByteString is, I just heard its faster than String when input is large).

However, when doing something like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B

main = do
    line <- B.getLine
    putStrLn . show $ B.length line
```

If I would pass the string: 10888869450418352160768000000

I get 30, but the length is 29.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Newline at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`B.getLine` includes the newline character at the end of your input in the `ByteString` it produces.